# Нарисовать график функции с двумя переменными

Tags: matlab

Задали нарисовать в matlab такой график:

[image]

Я не понимаю, дано ограничения для переменной x. А в функции только x0, x1. Ну я подумал, наверное, ограничение имеется в виду на обе переменные, сделал такой код:

```
Xmin(1) = -5;
Xmax(1) = 5;

Xmin(2) = -5;
Xmax(2) = 5;
dx1 = (Xmax(1)-Xmin(1))/49;
dx2 = (Xmax(2)-Xmin(2))/49;
x1 = Xmin(1):dx1:Xmax(1);
x2 = Xmin(2):dx2:Xmax(2);
n1 = length(x1);
n2 = length(x2);

    for i=1:1:n1
        for j=1:1:n2
            Y(i,j) = x1(i)^4-4*x1(i)^3+4*x1(i)^2+x2(i)^2;
        end
    end

surfc(x1,x2,Y), grid on;
xlabel('x1');
ylabel('x2');
zlabel('f(x)');
```

Но мне кажется, я всё-таки неправильно понял, что от меня хочет преподаватель. И протянул, нету возможности спросить, в понедельник сдавать нужно. Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я нарисовал график функции, предоставленной на скрине?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом похоже на правду, но вы явно запутались с индексами - у вас j не используется для переменных. А вообще я бы убрал циклы, а вместо них сгенерил прямоугольную сетку по двум координатам с помощью `[X1,X2] =  meshgrid(x1, x2);` и тогда вашу функцию можно посчитать просто как `Z=X1.^4+4*X1.^3+4*X1.^2+X2.^2` без всяких циклов, поверьте, оно в матлабе работает быстрее, да и преподаватели обычно именно этого хотят

Comment: Ого, спасибо Вам огромное. Но дело в том что там есть промежуток на котором нужно строить, как учесть промежуток в мешгрид?

Comment: Но, блин, графики разные получаются: http://pix.my/7T2radx9
Первый это моим спосбом, второй Вашем. Там у них разворот разный получился:)) Как можно повернуть трёхмерный график?

Comment: скорее всего если в вашем способе поменять местами i и j у Y графики совпадут, а поменять их судя по всему надо т.к. рост по оси x1 zdyj явно должен быть больше - при одинаковых значениях x1 входит с большими степенями (я говорю разумеется про программу т.к. в уравнении это x0). По поводу повернуть - что именно вы повернуть хотите? если всю сцену, то это функция rotate

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, разобрался!